# Convert decimal to IEEE Binary

Tags: java, ieee-754

I am trying to convert a number from decimal value to its IEEE 752 form. For example:

```
+43.9542 -> 01000010001011111101000100011010
-43.9542 -> 11000010001011111101000100011010
```

And I have written this method:

```
public float GetFloat32(String numero) {  

        //Convert
        int intBits = Integer.parseInt(numero, 2);
        float myFloat = Float.intBitsToFloat(intBits);

        //Exponent
        getExponent = 127 + (String.valueOf(Integer.toBinaryString(Math.abs((int) myFloat))).length() - 1);

        //Sign
        getSign = (myFloat < 0) ? 1 : 0;

        return myFloat;
    }
```

There is a problem that I cannot solve. I will make another example to make it clear.

```
double a = k.GetFloat32("01000010001011111101000100011010")
a = 43.9542
```

But when the number is negative, such as

```
double a = k.GetFloat32("1000010001011111101000100011010")
```

I get this error:

[image: Error message]

It means that my code works perfectly with positive numbers (including the zero) but with negative numbers it crashes. Where is the problem?

**Note**

I thought that I could solve my problem in this way

1. Check if `String numero` has a charAt(0) equal at 1
2. If yes (numero.charAt(0) == 1) then remove the first char
3. Call GetFloat32() with the new number (without the 1)
4. Return the result adding the - in front of the num

This could work but I would like to know where is the problem in the method above. I'd prefer avoiding this solution if possible.

Comment: Is there a reason to have the `getExponent` and `getSign` assignments in the method?

Comment: Are you aware of `Float.intBitsToFloat`?

Comment: Alberto, is your 752 a typo and do you mean 752 - the tag is ieee-754. In that case, Paul's suggestion is applicable. I couldn't find IEEE 752, so I didn't propose that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that int/Integer has an upper limit of 0x7FFF_FFFF and so the Integer.parseInt method won't go beyond this limit.

Use Long.parseLong, check the resulting value for exceeding 0x7FFF_FFFFL and handle according to the logic required for negative integer values.

Although, I don't see anything bad in your very own idea of stripping the sign bit and dealing with the rest to get the absolute value.

**Edit** There isn't a way to get the encoded float with a simple integer conversion from a bit string. Just consider that +1 and -1 in 32 binary digits according to two's complement representation differ in more than one bit, and 100....000 isn't -0. Signed magnitude isn't the same as two's complement. Moreover, Java's binary and hexadecimal (or any other base's) literals are meant to be positive quantities; if you need a negative value, use a sign.

**Later** Method Integer.parseUnsignedInt doesn't have an advantage over using Long, since you'll then have to know how use two's complement arithmetic to remove the leading (sign) bit to produce the absolute value which can then be split into exponent and mantissa. (Add or subtract Integer.MIN_VALUE.)

If there isn't IEEE 752 and IEEE 754 is the target format, the easiest form is

```
float f1 = Float.intBitsToFloat(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(numerio,2));
```

Comment: Now it's cleat thank you! I am going to use the solution that I thought with the charAt(0) thing :)

Comment: Wouldn't simply using `(int)Long.parseLong(...)` suffice? Also, integer literals in all radixes, not just hex and binary, are supposed to be positive. The `-` is not part of the literal.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Are we on different wavelengths? The Long.parseLong is in my answer, and I tried to express your "Also...literal" in the last sentence, edited 8 minutes ago.

Comment: @laune Java 8 has `Integer.parseUnsignedInt`, which would do the job just fine by itself.

Comment: @LoisWasserman No it won't. You would have a negative number in the resulting int, so it'll require a test against 0 and the addition of a certain number to obtain the absolute value following the sign. This isn't simpler. (Note: IEEE 752 is a signed magnitude representation.)

Answer (score 0):

public class IEEE754ToFloatingValues {

```
public static double convertToInt(String mantissa_str) {
    
    int power_count = -1;
    double mantissa_int = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mantissa_str.length(); i++) {
        // System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(mantissa_str.charAt(i) + ""));
        mantissa_int += (Integer.parseInt(mantissa_str.charAt(i) + "") * Math.pow(2, power_count));
        power_count -= 1;
    }

    IEEE754ToFloatingValues.logger.info((Object) "IEEE754ToFloatingValues : convertToInt :: end");

    return mantissa_int + 1.0;
}

public static String convertToBinary(int i) {
    
    return Integer.toBinaryString(i + 0b10000).substring(1);
}

public static String decimalToHex(String decimal) {

    int i = Integer.parseInt(decimal);
    System.out.println("<<>>" + i);
    String my_hexdata = Integer.toHexString(i);

    System.out.println(my_hexdata);

    return String.valueOf(ReturnFloatingValue(my_hexdata));

}

public static double ReturnFloatingValue(String my_hexdata) {

    

    String myString = "";
    if (my_hexdata == null) {
        return -2.0;
    }
    if (my_hexdata.length() != 8) {
        myString = String.format("%1$-" + 8 + "s", my_hexdata).replace(' ', '0');

        System.out.println("My hex data after appending 0's is : " + myString);
    }

    String binary = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(myString.charAt(i) + "", 16);
        binary += convertToBinary(num);
    }

    System.out.println("Binary length is :  " + binary.length());

    System.out.println("Binary number is : " + binary);
    if (binary == null || binary.isEmpty()) {

        return -3.0;
    }
    String ieee_32 = binary.substring(2);

    ieee_32 = String.format("%1$-32s", binary).replace(' ', '0');

    long sign_bit = Long.parseLong(new StringBuilder().append(ieee_32.charAt(0)).toString());

    long exponent_bias = Long.parseLong(ieee_32.substring(1, 9),    long exponent_unbias = exponent_bias - 127L;

    System.out.println("Exponent unbias is  : " + exponent_unbias);
    String mantissa_str = ieee_32.substring(9);

    double mantissa_int = convertToInt(mantissa_str);
    double real_no = Math.pow(-1.0, (double) sign_bit) * mantissa_int * Math.pow(2.0, (double) exponent_unbias);

    System.out.println("Real no is : " + real_no);
    return real_no;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //decimalToHex("0");
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe you can use this one to convert decimal value to hex and also floating point value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class IEEE754 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        float floa;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("ENTER A FLOATING POINT NUMBER");

        floa=sc.nextFloat();

        int no,sign;

        no=(int) floa;

        String a= Integer.toBinaryString(no);

        String sub=a.substring(1, a.length());

        if(floa<0)

        {

           sign=1;

        }

        else

        {

            sign=0;

        }

        int exp=a.length()-1;

        System.out.println(exp);

        int be=127+exp;

        String b= Integer.toBinaryString(be);

        System.out.print("biased exponent->");

        System.out.println(b);

        int loop=23-exp;

        float floatpart =floa-no;

        int q[]=new int[25];

        for(int i=1,j=0;i<=loop;i++,j++)

        {

            q[j]=(int) (floatpart*2);

            floatpart=floatpart*2;

            if(q[j]==1){

               floatpart=floatpart-1;

            }

        }

        System.out.print("mantissa->");

        System.out.print(sub);

        for(int k=0;k<q.length;k++)

        System.out.print(q[k]);

            System.out.println();

                        System.out.println("IEEE754 FORMAT IS");

                        System.out.print(sign+" "+b+" ");

                        System.out.print(sub);

        for(int k=0;k<q.length;k++)

        System.out.print(q[k]);

    }

}
```